# Sinatra - 504 Gateway Time-out The server didn't respond in time

Tags: timeout, sinatra, http-status-code-504

I am running a `sinatra` application on server. Often it generates a **time out error**.

> 504 Gateway Time-out The server didn't respond in time.

And some time it works well. I could not find out the cause of this. Any one please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This happened because of high load. I've created **2 more instances** of this (on haproxy). And increased the time out value. Now it works fine.